# Does $|f(n) − g(n)| \leq cn$ satisfy $f \in \Theta(g)$?

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics

So I'm trying to solve this asymptotic equation, here is how the question is formed:

"Let: $f : N \to N$, $g : N \to N$ and $h: N \to N$.

There exists natural numbers $n_0 \in N$ and $c \in N$, such that $|f(n) − g(n)| \leq cn$ for all $n \geq n_0$, prove or refute $f \in \Theta(g)$."

Big-O notation laws state that $f \in \Theta(g) = c_0 \cdot g(n) \leq f(n) \leq c_1 \cdot g(n)$,

which is a composition of both $O(n)$ and $\Omega(n)$.

$f(n) = O(g(n)) \rightarrow 0 \leq f(n) \leq c \cdot g(n)$

$f(n) = \Omega(g(n)) \rightarrow 0 \leq c \cdot g(n) \leq f(n)$

So I've formed the given equation as such:

$0 \leq  |f(n) - g(n)| \leq  c \cdot n$

Due to the fact the results are all natural numbers, the result of the equation should always be greater or equal to 0, thus it can be stated that $f(n)$ is always greater than or equal to $g(n)$, now in the case $f(n)$ is greater than, the given equation does not hold in $\Theta$, because it does not satisfy the $O(n)$ equation, is this enough evidence to refute the given statement or due to the fact that if $f(n)$ could be equal to $g(n)$ that there exists some constraint where the equation holds?

Comment: $f(n)>g(n)$ does not disprove the Theta (for example, $f(n)=g(n)+1\ne 1$ implies that $f(n)\le 2g(n)$, so $f(n)=O(g(n))$. You have to find another way.

Comment: Damn, youre right. Looking at the equations though, for the equation to satisfy both O(n) and $ \theta $ (n) it seems that f(n) must be equal to g(n), this proves the equation but I'm not sure how to transpose that mathematically, this is only my first algorithms class, so any help would be appreciated

Comment: That is also false: let $f(n) = n+1$ and $g(n)=n$. Then you have $f(n) =\Theta(g(n))$ since $g(n)\le f(n)\le 2g(n)$

Comment: Ah ok, so if I state what you have above, such that for the case f(n) > g(n),  f(n) = g(n) +1≠1 implies f(n) ≤ 2(g(n), proving f(n)=O(g(n)), then for  for c = 1, f(n) = n+1, g(n) = n, then f(n) = Ω(g(n)), implies g(n) < f(n), then this proves true for the given equation, no?

Comment: I've probably gotten that entirely wrong

Comment: What is confusing me in the original equation is that it seems c is a fixed variable, and in this case the given equation cant satisfy both O and Ω unless f(n) = g(n) and c=1

Comment: why? the example I gave you before satisfies everything

Comment: Thanks for that, but I'm just wondering if you look at the given equation $ | f(n) - g(n) | <= cn $ , should the $ c $ in that equation not have to satisfy both O and Ω ? for example $c = 1 , f(n) = n+1 , g(n) = n$ satisfies $Ω -> 0 <= c*g(n) <= f(n)$ but does not satisfy $O -> 0 <= f(n) <= c*g(n)$, because in the latter case $f(n) > c*g(n)$ no? but if we make $c=2$, the inverse is correct i.e. O satisifies, but Ω doesn't ?

Comment: Take $f(n)=\sqrt{n}$ and $g(n)=\text{ln}(n)$. $|f(n)-g(n)| \leq cn$ holds.

Comment: Unfortunately you can't use logs or square roots because the functions should produce a natural number as an output

Comment: Take $f(n) = \lfloor \sqrt{n} \rfloor$ and $g(n) = \lfloor \ln(n) \rfloor$, then.